# How can I disable the explanation of objects in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Explanation of functions/methods and objects appear while the cursor is on that particular piece of code. I want to disable this explanation.

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `settings.json` and add:

```
"editor.hover.enabled": false
```

Alternatively you can use settings editor, go to File -> Preferences -> Settings, search for `editor.hover.enabled` and uncheck the checkbox.

You can also customize the time until the hover is shown with `editor.hover.delay`.